# Cannot deselect text by tapping outside the selection in React Native Android Webview

Tags: android, webview, react-native

In chrome on Android, I can deselect selected text by tapping outside the selection. The selected text loses its blue highlight and the text selection menu disappears. Attempting to do the same on the same webpage loading within a React Native WebView on Android will not work. The text selection remains selected, nothing changes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm still not sure of exactly what caused this issue. But my solution was to disable FastClick.js. Doesn't seem like we even need it on Android.